# How to run the Statements in Parallel in Python3

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, python-3.6

```
s_t = obj.sock_recv(4096).decode('ascii')
    print(s_t)
    inp = input("Client reply!")
    obj.sock_send(str.encode(inp))
```

Can someone guide me how to run these statements in parallel, means if the s_t doesnot receive anything then the program don't stuck, but still exceute the further statements.

Comment: Keywords to search for: threading, multiprocessing, async…

Comment: Look into async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to make the the 'recv' non-blocking i.e. The 'recv' will return immediately if there is no data,

Then you can modify your code like this:

```py
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setblocking(0) # Add this line to socket object
```

And

```py
obj, addr = s.accept()
obj.setblocking(0)
```

If you are looking for asynchronous server then I believe asyncio is the way.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this in as it includes some catching of issues when you'd have a loop up and running already. It tripped me up before so might as well save you the headache.

```
import asyncio

async def getData1():
    s_t = obj.sock_recv(4096).decode('ascii')
    return

async def getInp1():
    inp = input("Client reply!")
    obj.sock_send(str.encode(inp))
    return

async def main():
    res = await(asyncio.gather(getData1(), getInp1())
    
if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    except RuntimeError:              
        loop = None

    if loop and loop.is_running():
        print('Async event loop already running')
        res1 = loop.create_task(main())
    else:
        print('Starting new event loop')
        res1 = asyncio.run(main())
```